# How to include a .js file in my XBL?

Tags: javascript, xbl

Is there a way to include a javascript file to a XBL instead of copy all the script to it?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/xbl/#the-implementation

Comment: @epascarello interesting.. if I use the src of the implementation I can't access the script functions from the handler tag. And if I use the src attribute of handler, and put all my code there, looks like the 'this' reference is not the same as before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I need to add it to the Xul file, so I can use it in the XBL.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is:

```
<xbl:script src="/xbl/foo/bar/myScript.js"/>
```

Comment: I was thinking of the implementation in xforms I believe.

Comment: +1 It is [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/xbl-primer/), but I'm having no success to use it.. maybe for Mozilla it is not implemented (as it is only docummented on the w3, but not on Mozilla Developer Network)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to run the script once and it doesn't need to access your document (i.e. it just defines methods) then the easiest way is to turn it into a module, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Components.utils.import but if you need the script to run once per element then you will need to use the subscript loader (see the link from the above page).